# Poppler installation for Mac OS 10.9

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, poppler

Would you have any idea what I should do to install Poppler on Mac OS X 10.9? FYI I am using Python 3.7 version now. 
I changed system recently, from Windows to not newest Mac, and some my programms which were working on Windows do not work on my Mac and I am changing the code of one of them.

And now I must install poppler to be able to use pdf2image as I saw on its github:

"How to install
First you need pdftoppm
pdftoppm is the piece of software that does the actual magic. It is distributed as part of a greater package called poppler.
Windows users will have to install poppler for Windows, then add the bin/ folder to PATH.
**Mac users will have to install poppler for Mac.**"

Otherwise, without poppler installed I can see:

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 169, in __page_count
raise Exception('Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?')
```

Exception: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

But when I try do it, below prompt appears:

```
pip3 install poppler
Collecting poppler
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement poppler (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for poppler.
```

I was checking version of installed modules and pdf2image==1.1.0.

I try to do it by brew but when I was installing it I saw that my version of Mac is not supported. 
Is any solution for this situation?

Thanks so much for your help in advance!

Comment: `poppler` is not a Python library, so you can't install it with `pip`. You'll need to download the source code and encoding data from https://poppler.freedesktop.org/. Then unpack and build it.

Comment: Thanks Wodin for your reply! I am new at MacOS and din't know that I can update Mac system for free and so quickly. I did it and change 10.9 version to 10.14 and install poppler per instruction on poppler website. It turned out to be the easiest way for me.

Comment: This is an old post, but I recommend: install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then `brew install poppler`